# NextJS getServerSideProps only works for one post, make any other freeze

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, freeze

### The issue

I'm building a blog with NextJS Typescript and MongoDB as a database.

I'm trying to fetch data with **getServerSideProps** to populate a **[slug].tsx** page (dynamic routing with slug query), but for some reason, the page **is indeed populated with data for a single specific post** but will not work with any other post (the page slows down the freezes, though a `useEffect` confirms that props have been passed from the server and set inside the `post` and `author` states).

I'll not use `getStatisProps` for modifications will be done on a regular basis.

There is no curcial difference between posts.

### The code

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({params}: any) => {

    const clientPromise = await getClient()

    const post = await clientPromise
        .db("my-db")
        .collection("articles")
        .findOne({ 'titleSlug': params.slug }, {projection: { "_id": 0 }})

    if (post) {
        const author = await clientPromise
            .db("my-db")
            .collection("auteurs")
            .findOne({ 'slug': post.authorSlug }, {projection: { "_id": 0 }})

        await clientPromise.close()
        return { props: { post: post, author: author}}
    }

    await clientPromise.close()
    return { props: { error: true }}

}

function Post (props: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>)  {

    const [post, setPost] = React.useState<any>(null)
    const [author, setAuthor] = React.useState<any>(null)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props)
        if (props.post) {
            setPost(props.post)
        }

        if (props.author ) {
            setAuthor(props.author)
        }
    }, [props])

    if (!props || !post || !author) { return null }

    return (
        <>
            <main className={"main"}>
                <Container maxWidth={"md"} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                    <PostView post={post} author={author} />
                </Container>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default Post
```

### Dependencies

```json
{
    "@types/node": "18.15.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "mongodb": "^4.8.0",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or render loops for the posts that don't work?

Comment: Nothing logged nor present in console. The page just freezes bug logs me that states are populated...

Comment: I've put logs in gssp and it only runs once, and there's no logs difference between pages that work and pages that don't work...

Comment: comment the PostView component and check if the behaviour persists

Comment: effectively, it worked - the issue seems to be related to a custom Image component... :/